# Importing work items into TFS from another system

Tags: c#, tfs, import

TL;DR: How can I createTFS work items as a specific state?

I am trying to import our work items from our old system (Rational Team Concert). There aren't any suitable automagic tools, so I'm doing it manually. I exported everything I need into a neutral format and plan on importing them with a simple-ish C# program (Json data that has all the attributes from RTC). I've already decided how to map the info from RTC to TFS.

My problem is, how can I import TFS work items as a specific state? There is only one valid initial state. I'm not above programatically moving the state through the workflow, but that seems a bit crazy.

Thanks. I'm hoping I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TFS Integration Platform (which I don't recommend using) has an option called EnableBypassRuleDataSubmission (see here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/11/10/tfs-integration-platform-what-is-the-enablebypassruledatasubmission-in-the-configuration-file-question-answer-7.aspx)

This is what allows it to create WI's directly into the desired state.  You should be able to use the same API's to do the same thing yourself.  Note: TFS Integration Platform is Open Source I believe, so you can track down it's source and see exactly how it accomplishes it.

Comment: That is what I needed. You also have to be using a "system" account.